# Destructuring with Spread in Node 6.5 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring, spread-syntax

According to this [compatibility table](http://node.green/), there should be no problem with destructuring or the spread operator in Node 6.5

However, this code here:

```
const things = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: true,
  d: false
};

const { a, b, ...rest } = things;

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
console.log(rest); // { c: true, d: false }
```

Throws this error:

```
const { a, b, ...rest } = things;
              ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Even though in this [babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=const%20things%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20d%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%2C%20b%2C%20...rest%20%7D%20%3D%20things%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%0D%0Aconsole.log(b)%3B%20%2F%2F%202%0D%0Aconsole.log(rest)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20c%3A%20true%2C%20d%3A%20false%20%7D&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=false) it works no problem.

Any ideas what's going on? (yes, I have Node 6.5 installed)

Comment: You're trying to use the experimental object rest syntax. The official rest syntax only works on arrays.

Comment: You even call it `rest`, why do you think this is spread syntax?

Comment: @ftor because i'm using the spread operator - the variable 'rest' is irrelevant, i could call it 'dog'.

Comment: @Bergi is there documentation anywhere on what counts as 'experimental' features?

Comment: @Jona No, the naming isn't irrelevant. Actually it describes your intention pretty well.

Comment: @Jona: Don't enable any of the `stage-N` presets and you don't get experimental features. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#stage-x-experimental-presets

Comment: @Bergi why on earth do rest and spread use the same syntax?

Comment: @ftor why on earth do destructuring and initialisers use the same syntax? Because convenience.